# What is the significance of "up to higher homotopies"?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

As far as I can understand, $E_\infty$ ring spaces are homotopy commutative H-spaces.  If we have a space, and we have an action of an $E_\infty$-operad on it, then we say that it has a homotopy commutative multiplication?

This seems to be what people say, however, there must be more right? In [the wikipedia article on $E_\infty$-operads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%E2%88%9E-operad), it is mentioned that what "$E_\infty$" gives us is a multiplication that is associative and commutative up to "all higher homotopies."  It also says that an $E_2$ space is a homotopy commutative $A_\infty$ space, i.e. if all we want is a commutative multiplication, up to homotopy, then we're done after the second level.  What is the significance of all these higher homotopies? I used to think the point was that we just wanted a way to get homotopy commutative spaces.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/57589/heuristic-behind-a-infty-algebras. Basically we want the homotopies themselves to satisfy certain relations, and so on, so on

Comment: Thanks. I guess my question is, I know what these relationships are, how they are parameterized essentially by discs, etc. but I don't know why we would want this.

Comment: Erm not discs actually, I was thinking of Associahedra, but the question remains.

Comment: Another link - try http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_structured_ring_spectrum

Comment: This is a fantastic article. Please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the comments this is explained very well on the wikipedia article http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_structured_ring_spectrum.

Basically the notions of $ E_\infty$ and $A_\infty$ spectra give additional structure to the spectrum, that allow for useful constructions (e.g. topological Hochschild homology)